# F#: how to convert expression to string

Tags: f#, tostring

Hello I have a been given the problem:

> Write an F# function *toString: aexpr -> string* to format expressions
>   as strings, with the binary operators written in inﬁx format. For
>   instance, it may format *Sub(Var "x", CstI 34)* as the string *"x -
>   34"*. For simplicity, put parentheses around any subexpressions, even
>   when they are superﬂuous according to the standard precedence rules
>   for arithmetic operators. Use the predeﬁned function string to convert
>   an integer value to its string representation.
>
> Hint: toString has very much the same structure as an eval function,
>   although it needs no environment argument because it uses variables
>   names, not variable values.

yes this is a HW problem. Any help would greatly be appreciated with explanations. Below I included an eval function

These are data types we have been using:

```
type oper1 = Neg | Not
type oper2 = Add | Mul | Sub | Less | Eq | And

type aexpr = 
  | C of int
  | V of string
  | Op1 of oper1 * aexpr
  | Op2 of oper2 * aexpr * aexpr

let rec eval e (env : (string * int) list) : int =
  match e with
  | CstI i            -> i
  | Var x             -> lookup env x 
  | Prim("+", e1, e2) -> (eval e1 env) + (eval e2 env)
  | Prim("*", e1, e2) -> (eval e1 env) * (eval e2 env)
  | Prim("-", e1, e2) -> (eval e1 env) - (eval e2 env)
  | Prim _ -> failwith "unknown primitive"
  | Let(x, e1, e2) -> eval e2 ((x, eval e1 env) :: env)
```

So for the given problem I have written:

```
let rec toString e (env : (string * int) list) : string
   match e with 
   | Prim("+", e1, e2) -> "e1 + e2"
   | Prim("*", e1, e2) -> "e1 - e2"
   | Prim("-", e1, e2) -> "e1 * e2"
```

this may look foolish, or am I on the right track? Fairly new to F#

Comment: I suppose you're going to want to write the specific values of e1 and e2, not just the names, and you're going to have to do it recursively, because those are expressions again, I assume.

Comment: Who assigns F# homework? Lucky!

Comment: Lucky?? HAHA not a fan

Answer (score 1):

The problem states:

> [...] although it needs no environment argument [...]

so your function `toString` should look something like this:

```
let rec toString e =
    match e with
    | CstI i            -> sprintf "%i" i // format number as string
    | Var  x            -> x              // already a string
    | Prim("+", e1, e2) -> sprintf "(%s + %s)" (toString e1) (toString e2)
    | Prim("*", e1, e2) -> sprintf "(%s * %s)" (toString e1) (toString e2)
    | Prim("-", e1, e2) -> sprintf "(%s - %s)" (toString e1) (toString e2)
```

For nested expressions `toString` is called on the subexpressions first. The resulting strings are then plugged into `%s` in `sprintf`.